# how to scroll divs horizontally inside the main

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

i am trying to scroll horizontally. it show the scroll bar but its not scrolling?? below is the

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>qwe</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 1000px; overflow-: scroll;">
    <div style="float: left;">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
    <div style="float: left;">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
    <div style="float: left;">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
    <div style="float: left;">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div style="float: left;">EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</div>
    <div style="float: left;">FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF</div>
    <div style="float: left;">GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: this is the output of above code]

Answer (score 3):

Give `display: inline` to child instead of `float:left` and `white-space: nowrap` to the parent.

```
<body>
<div style="width: 300px; overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap;">
    <div style="display: nline;">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
    <div style="display: nline;">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
    <div style="display: nline;">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
    <div style="display: nline;">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div style="display: nline;">EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</div>
    <div style="display: nline;">FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF</div>
    <div style="display: nline;">GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can give display: inline to child instead of using float:left and white-space: nowrap to the parent.

```
<body>
<div style="width: 300px; overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap;">
    <div style="display: nline;">aaaaaaa</div>
    <div style="display: nline;">bbbbbbb</div>
    <div style="display: nline;">ccccccc</div>
    <div style="display: nline;">ddddddd</div>
    <div style="display: nline;">eeeeeee</div>
    <div style="display: nline;">fffffff</div>
    <div style="display: nline;">ggggggg</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div is too wide so there is no need to display scroll indicators. 
Also, you have a small typo with `overflow-` instead of `overflow` css property.

If you want to horizontally scroll anyway, try to reduce the div width:

```
<body>
<div style="width: 300px; overflow: scroll;">
    <div style="float: left;">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
    <div style="float: left;">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
    <div style="float: left;">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
    <div style="float: left;">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD</div>
    <div style="float: left;">EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</div>
    <div style="float: left;">FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF</div>
    <div style="float: left;">GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: the div is small enough

Answer (score 0):

Not simply you can give a horizontal scrolling. And just showing scroller there won't make it scroll.
I have created a Codepen link which will surely help you to achieve your requirement.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/RgmZvm)

```
.container {  
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

article {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Check it and confirm if it is was your requirement or not.